# Compare Branches

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am doing prework for Bootcamp. In one section they are asking me to compare branches and do a pull request. One is in GitHub and the other is on my computer. When I go to compare a main branch and a feature/starter branch it tells me there is nothing to compare.

I have typed into the terminal what they asked me to do and it says "everything up to date". Then I went to GitHub and did what I think they told me to do and got a "nothing to compare answer". I am using windows 11 btw.

> Take a minute to review what we have done so far. We will follow these exact steps every time we work on a project in our boot camp, so it is important to keep practicing and memorize it!
>
> Now let’s take a closer look at the GitHub repository in our browser.
>
> a. Go to the GitHub repo in the browser, where the main branch is displayed by default. Select the branch feature/starter-code from the dropdown. Next, select the "Compare & pull request" button as seen in the following screenshot:
>
> [image]

Comment: I would just go through the steps again from the start and be sure you are following every instruction correctly. It is not possible for anyone to answer your question as we don't have really any information to go by. Perhaps there really are no differences between the two branches, so there really is "nothing to compare". That is most likely the case, actually. Try pushing up some changes to your feature branch, and then compare to the main branch (also by the way be sure you have pushed your changes on feature branch!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you set the correct base for the PR. If the base is correct (most probably master or main) and you still get "nothing to compare", make sure that you pushed actual changes compared to your base branch
[image]